# WPF MVVM C# паттерн и диалоговые окна с применением Command

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, wpf-commands

Не могу разобраться, можно ли сделать централизованный доступ к отдельной папке с командами во ViewModel. Имею некую папку Commands, в которой хочу размещать все команды. Их подключил к разметке, они работают. Но как отображать изменения во ViewModel, после отрабатывания команды? Конкретно сейчас проблема с открытием и загрузкой файла. Вызвать-то вызву команду, но как результат поместить во ViewModel? Они не связаны

**ViewModel**

```
using loopa.ViewModels.Base;

namespace loopa.ViewModels
{
    internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        private string _CurrentFilePath = "Не выбран";
        public string CurrentFilePath
        {
            get => _CurrentFilePath;
            set => Set(ref _CurrentFilePath, value);
        }



        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            // брать файл, если есть
        }
    }


}
```

**Command**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;

using loopa.Infrastucture.Commands.Base;

namespace loopa.Infrastucture.Commands
{
  internal class OpenFileCommand : Command
  {
    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
      OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
      ofd.Filter = ".txt|*.txt";
      ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;

      if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
        //Get the path of specified file
        var filePath = ofd.FileName;

        //Read the contents of the file into a stream
        var fileStream = ofd.OpenFile();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(fileContent);
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Как путь к файлу или что-либо еще поместить во ViewModel? Или обязательно размещать все в нее, и отделить не выйдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал немного по-другому.

Например вот такой класс команды:

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

И вот такой код во вьюмодели. Кстати вместо `Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`, мне кажется, лучше использовать `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` ([документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog?view=net-5.0)), зачем цепляться к огромной библиотеке Winforms ради одного диалога?

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

```cs
private ICommand _openFileCommand;

public ICommand OpenFileCommand => _openFileCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" };

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() ?? false)
    {
        string filePath = ofd.FileName;
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        MessageBox.Show(fileContent);
    }
});
```

Так как этот код теперь расположен во вьюмодели, то и все ее свойства и методы доступны.

XAML

```xml
<Button Content="Открыть файл..." Margin="5" Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}"/>
```

Мне конечно не нравится работа с диалогами во вьюмодели. Можно это в отдельный класс вынести и реализовать по-своему, но для начала и такой вариант вполне прилично выглядит.

Кстати

```cs
_CurrentFilePath = "Не выбран";
```

Не делайте так. Лучше оставьте его `null` по умолчанию

Вьюмодель не должна за поведение окна отвечать.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentFilePath, TargetNullValue=Не выбран}"/>
```

Если `CurrentFilePath` будет `null`, то текстблок сам напишет нужный текст.